# How can make a matcher for a string containing a substring, while ignoring case

Tags: dart, dart-unittest, dart-mock

I'm writing a unit test using mockito to mock a dependency and check we're calling it with the right argument. We should be passing in a string, so I'm trying to match on that function argument, but without asserting on the whole string, in case we change the wording. So I want to match on just one word in the message, but that word could be at the start of the sentence or in the middle, so it might start with a capital.

The dart matchers have [equalsIgnoringCase](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/equalsIgnoringCase.html), and [contains](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/contains.html), but I can't find any matcher that handles both, something like containsIgnoringCase. Is there any way to check for the substring, while also ignoring case in a matcher?

Comment: Why not just convert the strings to lowercase and perform the assertion?

Comment: @AjmalAli Ah, that makes sense for a basic assertion. I realise I should specify that in my case I'm also using mockito so I need to supply a matcher. I'll update the question, but I guessing in my case I might just have to create a new matcher.

Comment: Why don't you write your own ``Matcher``? Or use ``Matcher.matches(rexEx)``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP updated the question with the constraint that it should be a Matcher (for mockito):

It's possible to create Matchers with arbitrary code using `predicate`. In this case, using Ajmal's answer:

```
Matcher containsSubstringNoCase(String substring) =>
  predicate((String expected) => expected.contains(RegExp(substring, caseSensitive: false)));
```

Then:

```
expect('Foo', containsSubstringNoCase('foo'));  // true
```

Answer (score 30):

You can pass in a regex to the `contains` method with the `caseSensitive` property set to `false`.

```
string.contains(new RegExp(r'your-substring', caseSensitive: false));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I realised I have an extra constraint that means I can't just use `string.contains` or convert to lowercase, so I updated the question

Comment: That is not how RegExp flags are specified in Dart. You have to use `RegExp(r'your-substring', caseSensitive: false)` to make a regexp which ignores case.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest Way? This is how I did in DART but I believe it will be applicable for all languages.

```
 if (string1.toLowerCase().contains(string2.toLowerCase())) {
    //TODO: DO SOMETHING
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, not too obvious from the question title but I'm actually looking for a matcher that meets that criteria to use with mockito, not just an if statement

Comment: A little bit late, but you for future readers: you can create Mockito matchers with arbitrary code using predicate:

`Matcher containsSubstringNoCase(String substring) => predicate((String expected) => expected.toLowerCase().contains(substring.toLowerCase()));`